# Wordpress - Image title is exist - Gutenberg not taking it automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Before asking this question, i paid 9 hours from 10:00AM to 20:00PM :(
I tried everything ... but have no luck.

Well, i already set image's informations: alt text, title, caption, description

[image]

The gutenberg editor can take the Alt text, image caption but missing the "Title" at advanced -> Title attribute tab.

[image]

How can i make Gutenberge take Titles from image post_id without rewrite it again manually ?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I tested adding an image with a title set in WordPress 6.2 and confirm that the title attribute is not added by default.

On reviewing the source code, I found the `title` key is not included in `imageProps` of [pickRelevantMediaFiles](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/ed2c93c2190e1fe1e7a5727922d096cbdd22172e/packages/block-library/src/image/edit.js#L46) - despite being a block attribute in the [image block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/ed2c93c2190e1fe1e7a5727922d096cbdd22172e/packages/block-library/src/image/block.json#L36) and `title` being commonly used. Seems to be related to [Post featured image: Add title attribute #46880](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/46880) PR on GitHub (currently blocked at time of writing).

A potential solution could be [extending the edit()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) function of the image block to include `title` eg:

```js
export const pickRelevantMediaFiles = ( image, size ) => {
    const imageProps = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries( image ?? {} ).filter( ( [ key ] ) =>
            [ 'alt', 'id', 'link', 'caption', 'title' ].includes( key ) 
            // Added 'title' to prevent value being "undefined"
        )
    );
...
}
```